# Onclick respeitar campo required

Tags: javascript, html5

Criei uma animação que aparece na tela e bloqueia os campos digitados pelo usuário enquanto a requisição é processada, diretamente no `submit`, conforme abaixo:

```
onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('aguarde').style.display = 'block'; block();"
```

Aparecendo a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acontece que se o usuário não preencher alguma informação, o formulário não é enviado e aparece o aviso devido ao *required*, mas a animação é executada de qualquer forma, e para voltar a página somente atualizando a mesma.

Existe alguma forma do `onClick` aguardar a validação dos campos `required` antes de executar essa animação?

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso o `onclick` será executado de qualquer forma. Para que essa validação de bloqueio seja ativada somente se os critérios forem preenchidos, coloque dentro o evento `onsubmit` e tire do `onclick`. Pode ser algo como:

```
document.getElementById('meu_form').addEventListener("submit", function(){
    document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('aguarde').style.display = 'block'; 
    block();
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Alterei a função mas não funcionou, nem chamou a animação.

Comment: No lugar do `meu_form` vai o *id* do seu formulário. Acredito que `onlick` postado estava no no `input` type submit, certo?! Ele só vai cair no submit se os required tiverem sidos satisfeitos.

Comment: Sim, alterei com a id do meu form, mas não funcionou. Vou tentar novamente.

Comment: Beleza. Se não conseguir e puder criar um Fiddle, eu te ajudo =]

Comment: Funcionou, coloquei direto no evento do form e tirei tudo do submit. +1. Abraço e obrigado.

Comment: acabei de achar um "erro". Ele aciona a animação somente no segundo clique do submit. Se eu preencho tudo corretamente ele não aciona a animação, somente se eu clico primeiro "chamando" o erro, ai depois que eu preencho tudo ele funciona. Tem algo mais que preciso fazer?

Comment: Não tem @Diego, sem ver como está seu HTML fica dificil dizer. Provavelmente por algum outro motivo no seu código deve estar gerando esse comportamento.

Comment: O código é muito grande, salvei ele aqui se vc puder dar uma olhada: http://200.208.251.153/InsereReserva.txt

Comment: desculpe pedir, mas chegou a ver o codigo?